# Heston Model Maximum Return Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-volatility, heston

What is the joint probability distribution of the maximum of the return between time $0$ and $t$ and the return at $t$, for the Heston model, when the return drift is $0$ and the correlation between the equity factor and the variance factor is **nonzero**?

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/24970/59 doesn't answer your question, but may help. Essentially, you're asking for the chance a limit order at a given price will be filled.

Comment: Thank you, @barrycarter. Though it does not answer my particular question, your answer has a lot of information. I will research it later. By the way, at one glance, for the probability of touch you should note that the accepted answer is wrong and my answer is correct.

Comment: Hmmm, hadn't read that one carefully, you might be right.