# How to calculate the elapsed time until a stock reach a certain price?

Tags: equities, price, time

In specific, I will set a certain price to a stock and I want to know how long takes until the historical prices reach this price.
Thanks you.

Comment: Is http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24970/estimate-probability-of-limit-order-execution-over-a-large-time-frame helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no simple answer, but with some assumptions on price generating process you can try to come up with some estimates. If you assume ABM, then your expected time until a price reaches a certain level is infinite [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531225/expected-stopping-time-of-brownian-motion)]. But you can also derive probability density of how long you would have to wait [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift)].

Maybe some smarter forum member would add if there are similar formulas for GBM.