# Probability of getting a fill of a given size

Tags: limit-order-book, order-execution

Question is quite simple, what is the **probability of getting a fill** for:

> *(i) a limit order of size - $s$*
>
> *(ii) that is $\Delta$ away from the mid-price*
>
> *(iii) in the next $t$ minutes*

given empirical data of the market orders (prices and sizes of the fills, as well as the time of the fills). I think the Poisson process is useful here?

I have found [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24970/estimate-probability-of-limit-order-execution-over-a-large-time-frame/25074#25074). Although it asks this question for the longer-timeframe, I suppose my question is a generalization of that question.

I would like to know this to optimally place the limit orders with varying sizes at varying distances from the mid-price to obtain the largest expected value of the fills. It would also be useful to know the expected order size at a given distance from the mid-price.

Also, according to [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47118/how-can-one-effectively-approximate-the-fill-portion-of-a-limit-order-in-a-fifo), what I am attempting to do might be nonsensical? And I should just base placing of the limit orders on game theory?